# Store data across two or more removable disks in Windows, perhaps also in Linux, for security

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, security, raid

I want to store some data in something like a stripped or spanned volume, or a RAID, but on flash drives. I'm basically trying to replicate this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dougISKs2vQ) in Windows.

I know all the problems related to doing this; I don't care. If there's a better way to do this, I'll be happy to hear it, I just want the effect that the data on the drives is only accessable if you plug in all the flash drives; if one of them is lost, the data must be gone.

It would be amazing if there was a way to do this such that it would work on both Linux and windows, but at minimum I need a solution for Windows 10.

Thanks in advance